# why screenshot has no save function in ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, npm

I am trying to take a screenshot of my ionic app.
I have run these commands first.

```
npm i com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot
npm i @ionic-native/screenshot
```

my app.module.ts looks like this.

```
import { Injectable, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, HammerModule, HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from 
  '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { Base64ToGallery } from '@ionic-native/base64-to-gallery/ngx';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { Screenshot } from '@ionic-native/screenshot/ngx';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,        
            IonicStorageModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [
     StatusBar,
     SplashScreen,
     { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
     Base64ToGallery,
     Screenshot
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Home.page.ts looks like this

```
...
import { Screenshot } from '@ionic-native/screenshot/ngx';
...
constructor(private screenshot: Screenshot) {}
screenShot() {
    this.screenshot.save('jpg', 80, 'screenshot.jpg').then(res => {
        console.log("saved.');
    }
}
```

screenShot() function is the function that is called when the button is clicked.
but my app shows me the following error.
[image: chrome browser error]
can anyone of you help me how to fix this error?
I will be very grateful for any kind of help
Thanks in advance

Comment: just in case, my project is a capacitor project.

Comment: It looks like your service Screenshot is undefined for your component, did you try to debug it? to check is correctly injected?